# Finding normal probabilities and quantiles

Tags: statistics

Male basketball players at the high school, college, and professional ranks use a regulations basketball that weighs an average of 22.0 ounces with a std dev of 1.0 ounce. Assume that the weights of basketballs are approx. normally distributed. (Round to nearest tenth of a percent)

a. What % of regulation basketballs weigh less than 19.5 ounces?

b. What % of regulation basketballs weigh more than 23.1 ounces?

c. What % of regulation basketballs weigh b/w 19.5 and 22.5 ounces?

d. What is the weight of a basketball if its weight is at the 85th percentile (or top 15%)?

Comment: Normcdf and InvNorm in a ti-83 can solve all these questions for you

Comment: He probably can't use that on his exam

Comment: @knrumsey This is most likely homework. But you make a point

Comment: If you need to know how to find these answers using printed normal tables, please edit an attempt into your question, and leave a note.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will demonstrate the usage of normCdf and invNorm in a graphing calculator to solve problems like these, though they can be solved like the answer given by Techie91.

The notation for normalcdf is *NormalCDF(lower bound, upper bound, mean, standard deviation)*

Part A:

$$NormalCDF (-100, 19.5, 22, 1) =.006$$

Part B:

$$NormalCDF (23.1, 100, 22, 1) =.135$$

Part C:

$$NormalCDF(19.5,22.5,22,1) = .685$$

*NOTE that these are percentages, so multiply by 100 to get %)*

**The usage of -100 or 100 serves as a lower or upper bound, respectively. You could probably get the same results using 50 (or some value that's far enough from the mean). I like to use 1000 or even 10000 just to be safe.**

The notation for InverseNorm is *InversNorm(area to the left or right **(depending what the question asks, such as top 15% or bottom 15%)**, mean, standard 
deviation)*

Part D:
$$InverseNorm(.85,22,1) = 23.03$$

*This is of course a weight, in this case ounces*

Comment: In R, > `pnorm(19.5, 22, 1)` returns 0.006209665; 
`1-pnorm(23.1, 22, 1)` returns 0.1356661; `diff(pnorm(c(19.5, 22.5), 22, 1))` returns 0.6852528; and `qnorm(.85, 22, 1)` returns 23.0364. So using $\pm 100$ for $\pm \infty$ gives approximations that are plenty good enough for the requested accuracy.

Comment: Good point. thanks for supplying the R code. Not everyone is familiar with computer software methods but I always like to use computer software as much as possible, and check my work by hand. Of course computer software is much faster and usually more efficient. I'm assuming the mechanics behind "normalCDF" in a graphing calculator is the same as "pnorm" in R?

Comment: Both are probably using piecewise 'rational approx' fcns for the normal CDF. R uses Wichura's algorithm which is about as accurate as can be represented in double precision floating point; his algorithm is also invertible so can be used for quantiles. That algorithm would probably take too much memory in a calculator and be overkill for the promised accuracy.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you need to find the z-score and use the Z table. where x_bar = 22 ounces, sigma = 1 ounce. you need to use the equation Z = (x-x_bar)/sigma

a) you need to find P(Z). x = 19.5. solve for Z, then find P(Z) using the Z table, where P(Z) is the area under the curve. look up how to use the Z table. here is one you can use. There are several Z tables available, so make sure you are consistent

http://d2r5da613aq50s.cloudfront.net/wp-content/uploads/360197.image0.jpg

b) Same as a.

c) you need to find P(x = 22.5) and P(x = 19.5). and find the area between the two points.

d) P(Z) = 0.85, Look this up on the Z-table, and work backwards to find x.